# Spark load Data for Decision tree - Change Label in LabelledPoint

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I try to do the example for decision tree in spark at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-decision-tree.html

I have downloaded a1a dataset from http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary.html#a1a

The dataset is in LIBSVM format where the two classes have labels +1.0 and -1.0
When I try

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.util.MLUtils

// Load and parse the data file.
val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "/user/cloudera/testDT/a1a.t")
// Split the data into training and test sets (30% held out for testing)
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.7, 0.3))
val (trainingData, testData) = (splits(0), splits(1))

// Train a DecisionTree model.
//  Empty categoricalFeaturesInfo indicates all features are continuous.
val numClasses = 2
val categoricalFeaturesInfo = Map[Int, Int]()
val impurity = "gini"
val maxDepth = 5
val maxBins = 32

val model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(trainingData, numClasses, categoricalFeaturesInfo,
 |   impurity, maxDepth, maxBins)
```

I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: GiniAggregator given label -1.0 but requires label is non-negative.

So I tried to change the label -1.0 to 0.0. I tried something like

```
def changeLabel(a: org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint) =
 { if (a.label == -1.0) {a.label = 0.0}  }
```

Where I get error:

> reassignment to val

So my question is this: How can I change the labels of my data? Or is there a workaround so DecisionTree.trainClassifier() to work with data with negative labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You cannot resign value argument of a `Product` class, and even if it was possible (declared as `var`), you **should never**  modify data in place in Spark.

How about:

```
def changeLabel(a: org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint) = 
  if (a.label == -1.0) a.copy(label = 0.0) else a
```

```
scala> changeLabel(LabeledPoint(-1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)))
res1: org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint = (0.0,[1.0,2.0,3.0])

scala> changeLabel(LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)))
res2: org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint = (1.0,[1.0,2.0,3.0])
```